# Migrate from Laravel 5.5 to Angular 4

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I have a project that use Laravel, with a bit of VueJS, and JQuery.

I want now to introduce Angular 4 into the project, so I was thinking:

- Limit Laravel to an API with no front end ( Maybe migrate to Lumen )
- Create an external Angular project that will consume the API.

It is important to say that I am new to Angular, I have a week seeing it.

How should I plan the migration? Step by Step? How would you do it?

- It would be great to do it by parts, so, is it possible to have only 1 page managed with Angular for instance?
- Should I also migrate routing to angular?
- Should I also migrate internationalisation to angular?
- Should I also migration authentication to angular. This part is the typical part I would like to avoid, as I am quite fine with Laravel authentication. I know I will have to check if the user is authenticated, probably with JWT, but all the login pages, are quite ok for me only with Laravel
- Is it possible to have the Angular mixed in Laravel project, as I actually use VueJS, or is it mandatory to have a separated project.
- if not, is it good to first mix Laravel / Blade / Angular, and in a second step, migrate everything to a new front end

Thanks !

Comment: Laravel = serverside. Angular = purely client side. You're asking questions which highlight that you're absolutely confused.. or something happened recently and angular became server side framework as well, in which case I'm confused and not up to date.

Comment: lol, you're right, but right now, I have almost pure Laravel app. I would like to include Angular for better UX.

Comment: At the end, What I shall have is my server side project will just be an API, and my front end project will be 100% Angular that will consume API, what I don't know is how to do it

Comment: Well, quite honestly, there's always a way, but I don't see what exactly you're migrating. Your serverside / RESTful API is done by using Laravel. The rest is done by using Angular, which means you can simply boostrap angular project and have it consume your Laravel API. Personally, I think Vue does quite a bit (you can google `awesome vue` and get a huge list of great components), and given the fact that Laravel comes with excellent Laravel Mix which bundles stuff for you and provides HMR - I'd question the decision to move over to Angular. **I'll highlight that this is purely my opinion**.

Comment: Angular decision comes because I will have to work in my professional life with Angular.

Comment: Ok, I'd suggest you go through [Laravel Mix documentation](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/tree/master/docs#readme). I didn't try to use Angular with it, but judging from current experience and docs - there's no reason why it wouldn't work. Other option you have is  to spin up an angular project on its own and simply point it to RESTful backend based on Laravel. Good luck!